# How can I get localizations to resolve from IStringLocalizer using Hellang problem details middleware?

Tags: c#, localization, c#-8.0

I am using a .NetCore 8 API project running on Docker using a Linux image. My aim is to localize the error messages returned in the Hellang problem details mapping.

The code shown below is a simplified version of what I am actually doing but also doesn't work (ie. localizedErrorMessage is "UserAlreadyExists" and allStrings are empty).

```
 builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(x => {
     x.CustomizeProblemDetails = ctx =>
     {
         var localizer = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IStringLocalizer<ErrorHandling>>();
         var allStrings = localizer.GetAllStrings();
         var localizedErrorMessage = localizer[FailureCode.UserAlreadyExists.ToString()]; 
...
```

**Note:** I have also checked the culture here and it is reflective of what is supplied in the initial request (the default is en-US).
[image]
[image]

**Note:** I have also ensured the middleware is called AFTER the localization middleware

```
...
builder.ConfigureLocalization();
builder.ConfigureProblemDetails();
...
```

I know I have set everything up correctly in regards to the resource file/DI etc. because it resolves when I call it like shown in the code below from the API controller method (using the same snippet as in the code above with the obvious exception of not using "HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService").

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto?>> CreateUserAsync([FromBody] CreateNewUserDto model)
{
    var allStrings = _localizer.GetAllStrings();
    var localizedErrorMessage = _localizer[FailureCode.UserAlreadyExists.ToString()];
...
```

Can anyone help direct me to a solution/explain why it won't resolve (load the resource translations) in the middleware?

**Note:** I also know I could avoid having to do this in the middleware by resolving it when throwing the exception as shown below but I think it is much cleaner to do it in the middleware since I won't have to inject IStringLocalizer everywhere and there will also be resource duplication (across microservices).

```
throw new XYZException(_localizer[FailureCode.UserAlreadyExists.ToString()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up NOT using the .resx files to load the localizations - I wrote a custom resolver which gets the resources from a database (actually from another microservice). ie.

```
public class ApiResourceStringLocalizer : IStringLocalizer 
{
     ....


 builder.Services.AddScoped<IStringLocalizer, ApiResourceStringLocalizer>();
```

This is what I wanted to do anyway but in regards to this question, it is a workaround.